# wordpress php author meta data condition

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I want to show no author if im not on a blog post, currently Im have it picking up the author on the blog post, but if bi navigate to a different page (non blog post) i want no author.

**My code**

```
global $post;
if ( is_singular() ) {
    $author = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $post->post_author);
} else {
    $author = 'no author';
}
```

Comment: You should define the post type for blog posts, I think it's the default so then:
`is_singular('post')`
Should work

Comment: Perfect, thank you. easy fix. can you believe i was at this for 1 hr lol